# How to write SQL Server query which can give result from any of 4 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables (say emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4) with nearly identical columns. I want to fetch details

```
(select empid, empname from emp1 where empid = '1' )
UNION
(select empid, empname from emp2 where empid = '1')
UNION
(select empid, empname from emp3 where empid = '1')
UNION
(select empid, empname from emp4 where empid = '1')
```

The thing is if I got result from first query (emp1) it should ignore queries below (emp2, emp3, emp4). If I get a result from emp2, it should ignore (emp3, emp4) and so on.

Remember in emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4 there an be different `empname` associated with same `empid`. That's why union giving all the results. In that case I have to prefer result from uppermost table i.e emp1 > emp2 > emp3. I also tried using 'case' but things are not working for me.

Sample data

emp1

```
1    deepak
```

emp2

```
1    nitin
```

emp3

```
1    sateesh
```

emp4

```
1    chandra
```

and expected result is

```
1 deepak
```

I hope I am clear to you. please help me thank you

Comment: i can give the result with case but it will be highly not recommend ... i will wait for 1 hour so if no answer then i will post my answer

Comment: So are you trying to say that if any results come back from `emp1` you don't want `emp2` to be queried? Or do you mean if you get `1, 'Jimmy'` back from `emp1` you don't want to see `1, 'Jimmy'` again from `emp2`?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: @PhilWalton emp1 can have 1,'PhilWalton ' emp2 can have 2,'Jimmy' in that case i want to print 1,'PhilWalton  only

Comment: @wewesthemenace i have edited post please check it

Comment: @Dhaval please post your answer it may work  me thank you for your quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an arbitrary column to specify the priority.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02e9e/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *, N = 1 FROM emp1 WHERE empId = 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT *, N = 2 FROM emp2 WHERE empId = 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT *, N = 3 FROM emp3 WHERE empId = 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT *, N = 4 FROM emp4 WHERE empId = 1
)
,CteRN AS(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N) FROM Cte
)
SELECT 
    empId, empName
FROM CteRN
WHERE RN = 1
```

---

Basically, you want to prioritize results from `emp1`, then `emp2` and so on. This is where the arbitrary column `N` comes in. You want to *rank* them in order of priority. The result of the first CTE is:

```
empId       empName    N
----------- ---------- -----------
1           deepak     1
1           nitin      2
1           sateesh    3
1           chandra    4
```

Then you use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to add a sequential number to each rows. The second CTE, `CteRN` will give you:

```
empId       empName    N           RN
----------- ---------- ----------- --------
1           deepak     1           1
1           nitin      2           2
1           sateesh    3           3
1           chandra    4           4
```

Laslt, you only want the row with the least `RN`, so you add a `WHERE RN = 1` clause. The final result would be:

```
empId       empName
----------- ----------
1           deepak
```

*Additionally, you can add a `PARTITION BY empId` on `RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N)`*

Comment: i didn't got anything from this can you please explain this

Comment: What do you mean? Does it not give any result?

Comment: i think you need to `partition by empid` in `RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N) FROM Cte` to make it work properly

Comment: @ughai Sure, if the OP is filtering for more than one `empId`, adding a partition is a good idea.

Comment: @wewesthemenace it's giving result plus performance benefits but i am not able to understand the query as i am beginner i will appreciate  if you can explain it

Comment: Ow, I'll update my answer to include some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question, since empid should not be repeated from other tables, you can try something like this.

```
select empid,empname 
from emp1
UNION ALL

select empid,empname 
from emp2 e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT empid FROM emp1 ee WHERE ee.empid = e.empid)
UNION ALL

select empid,empname 
from emp3 e
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT empid FROM emp1 ee WHERE ee.empid = e.empid)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT empid FROM emp2 ee WHERE ee.empid = e.empid)
UNION ALL

select empid,empname from emp4 e
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT empid FROM emp1 ee WHERE ee.empid = e.empid)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT empid FROM emp2 ee WHERE ee.empid = e.empid)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT empid FROM emp3 ee WHERE ee.empid = e.empid)
```

Comment: I liked your suggestion i will wait for some time to get better solution if you have any other solution in mind pleae help me otherwise i will accept this after some time

Comment: also try the solution wewesthemenace suggested, it's simple and might give better performance

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but it works.

```
INSERT INTO emp3
SELECT 1, 'pwalton'

INSERT INTO emp4
SELECT 2, 'jimmy'

DECLARE @myTable TABLE (empid INT, empname VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @myTable
SELECT empid, empname FROM emp1

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @myTable)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @myTable
    SELECT empid, empname FROM emp2
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @myTable)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @myTable
    SELECT empid, empname FROM emp3
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @myTable)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @myTable
    SELECT empid, empname FROM emp4
END

SELECT * FROM @myTable
--results: 1    pwalton
```